# Atualizar Lista de objetos via entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, lista, sql-update

Bom dia!
Queria pedir a ajuda de vocês só pra saber se existe um modo melhor de ser feito.

hoje tenho uma lista de objetos do tipo

> Formatacao_RelatorioLinhaDeletada

e realizo um foreach nessa lista, pegando item por item dando o attach e salvando as modificações no banco conforme o código abaixo:

```
db.Formatacao_RelatorioLinhaDeletada.Attach(obj);
db.Entry<Formatacao_RelatorioLinhaDeletada>(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;

return (db.SaveChanges() > 0);
```

Gostaria de saber se consigo realizar um attach para lista todo como se tivéssemos executando um SQL conforme o abaixo que atualiza múltiplos registros com um único Update:

```
UPDATE TABELA SET a = 2 WHERE TESTE > 0
```

Aguardo a discussão da galera mas desde já agradeço!

Comment: existem maneiras de se fazer isso, uma é com SQL Pura pelo `Entity Framework`, outra é trazer os dados e alterando a lista dando um `SavingChanges()` se for poucos registros funciona bem, tudo depende de contextos se puder dizer algo mais, como você traz a lista, quantos registros vem, quer criar um método e resolver esse problema basicamente com SQL pura?

Comment: A lista vem com muitos registros porem é exatamente o modelo da tabela no entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso é utilizando o [Entity Framework Extended.](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)

Primeiro, basta instalar a library via o seguinte comando NuGet:

> Install-Package EntityFramework.Extended

Depois, basta fazer o update. Um exemplo seria:

```
context.Tasks.Where(t => t.Teste > 0)
              .Update(t => new Task { a = 2 });
```

Dessa forma ele irá atualizar todos os dados da tabela **Task** onde `Teste > 0`.

Caso queira fazer na mão, sempre pode utilizar o [Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg679456(v=vs.113).aspx). Dessa forma o seu código seria algo parecido com isso:

```
var sql = "UPDATE [TABELA] SET a = 2 WHERE TESTE > 0";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
```

Caso queira passar parâmetros, [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5474264/4843158) possui vários exemplos de como fazer isso.

Comment: O problema é que eu já tenho a lista queria só dar um update nela..
Nesse caso o where do exemplo acima não atenderia.

Comment: @ArthurZanini Update no banco ou apenas nos itens da lista para fazer alguma outra operação?

Comment: seria uma atualização no proprio banco

Comment: @ArthurZanini Dessa forma ele atualiza o banco. Mas ele também aceita passar uma lista (`IQueryable`), como mostra na [documentação oficial](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Batch-Update-and-Delete)